# Did the Resistance know about Starkiller Base and if not, how was it hidden so well?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I don't recall this being explained in the movie, but did the Republic/Resistance have any idea the Starkiller base existed before it

> Completely obliterated the Hosnian Prime system?

Did no one notice the fact that something way bigger than the Death Star was wandering around the area eating entire stars for nefarious purposes? Surely a patrol or a trade ship would have noticed something while the Starkiller was being constructed, or someone would have noticed the massive amount of supplies being obtained by the First Order to build the Starkiller that probably took a couple of years to build, and someone would have investigated.

Or was the First Order that good at playing hide and seek with an entire planet of death?

Comment: They had plans for it at hand pretty quickly for just having found out it existed...

Comment: I believe the Starkiller was located inside First Order territory and wasn't mobile.  (Its special trick was that it could destroy planets anywhere in the galaxy.)

Comment: @MikeEdenfield That is true, but I was surprised that they were able to hide the Starkiller for that long, up to the destruction of the you-know-what system.

Comment: @HarryJohnston If they couldn't move it, then how would they be able to eat more than one star for energy?  Seems like they would eat the one or two in their system and then not be able to fire again, unless there were more stars close by.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I thought it was briefly said to be mobile during the initial Resistance briefing - something about hyperspace drive or something along those lines (I've only seen it twice - will have to pay more attention next week)

Comment: Of note, it was [built inside an existing planet](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111481/5184), and the original Death Star was only the size of a small moon. It's unlikely to have drawn much attention during construction, only when the planet started moving around and firing mega lasers halfway across the galaxy.

Comment: @Toothless: My interpretation was that the weapon only sucked energy from the outer layers of the sun, i.e., they just had to wait a bit for the sun to recharge and then they could use it again.  There was nothing I could see in the movie to suggest the planet had hyperspace capabilities.  (But even if it did move from system to system, it could have remained in First Order territory.)

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell - nope. It **fired** throigh hyperspace. The **ultimate gun that can shoot around the corners**

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - many Bothans died....

Comment: [Space is big. Really big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NjSPKxt4ts)

Comment: I agree with @HarryJohnston.  My impression was that it's 'stationary' in the sense that your typical planet is 'stationary' in a particular orbit around its star, and not something that goes "wandering around the area eating entire stars".  And that it only _temporarily_ consumed the power of its host star when charging (if you're capturing the entire energy output of a star, a few moments is plenty for annihilating a trifling handful of planets).  However the film seems to contradict this when the second shot is charged (and again when its destruction causes a new star to form).

Comment: @Toothless - is there anything my answer lacking that I can improve so you can find it acceptable? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### 1. No, they did not know about Starkiller base before.

TFA novelization by Alan Dean Foster establishes that (and, ironically, answers your presumably sarcastic quip about "Surely a patrol or a trade ship would have noticed something" ! :)

> In the main conference room of the base on D’Qar, an ongoing strategy session had brought together the leaders of the Resistance. Leia, Poe, C-3PO, Han, and an assortment of senior officers including Statura and Ackbar were assembled around a three-dimensional map of an **isolated, frozen planet that up until now had not been worth a hopeful visit from a minor trading ship**. Finn was present, too, since **it was his information about the world in question that had prompted the gathering**.
>
> **“The scan data from Captain Snap Wexley’s reconnaissance flight confirms everything Finn has told us,” Poe announced to the group.
>   Wexley spoke up. “They’ve built a new kind of hyperspace weapon within the planet itself**. Something that can fire across interstellar distances in the equivalent of real time.” His expression showed his incredulity. “I’ve had my share of technical training, but I can’t even imagine how that’s possible.”

### 2. If you look at the Galaxy Map in the Visual Dictionary, Starkiller base isn't exactly where everyone would be likely to look.

- Starkiller base is not only out **in the middle of nowhere on the edge of the Galaxy**
- It's in the **Unknown Regions** specifically, where few people go.

  There was a reason First Order retreated there.
- It's directly on the **opposite side** of the Galaxy from the Rebellion's center on D'Quar

  [image]

### 3. How would anyone know what they are looking at anyway?

It's NOT a giant metal moon. It's a **real planet**.

You wouldn't know something was amiss even if there was a trading ship around  (and as shown in #1, there wasn't).

Comment: The novelization sounds like it might be worth a read.  Thanks for that.  I wasn't trying to introduce sarcasm in my initial post if it came across that way - just curiosity as to how they kept it secret.  I'm reminded of the "Loose Lips Destroy Ships" picture that was posted in another thread about TFA.

Comment: @Toothless - too bad. It was a good kind of sarcasm :)

Comment: oO THAT far? how the hell did they manage to cross that distance in just a mere 30 m inutes? oO

Answer (score 9):

I think *The Force Awakens* has established one fact above all others:

The *Star Wars* universe is vast, and the search technologies available are weak.

They literally couldn’t find a planet *with an annotated map*. The planets on the map even had names!

But even with amazing search and mapping capabilities, we’d still be left with the fact that the “Galaxy Far Far Away” is still *a galaxy*. It is made of billions of stars, and apparently a majority of them have planets.

[image: Carl Sagan answered this question]

Comment: @JakeGould Hah, well they should rethink that. Han is incredibly strong in the Force -- he just *doesn't know it*.

Comment: @JakeGould Han does explain later when they land on Takonda that the reason they are there is to get clean ships because (paraphrasing slightly as only seen it once) "If Chewie and I can track the Falcon you can bet the First Order can too"

Answer (score 0):

This has stood out to me as a major flaw in the narrative of TFA and I don't feel as if the aforementioned responses are convincing enough. Even if we accept that this system is so remote in the galaxy that the Republic had never even visited or seen it, how would the First Order even be able to test Starkiller Base unnoticed? This weapon is draining the freaking Sun! The entire system would feel the effects of this. This isn't to suggest that there must be other inhabited planets nearby, this may may very well be completely remote, but there's no way the First Order would be able to even test this weapon without drawing suspicion. It must have taken a dozen if not hundreds of tests to perfect this technology. How many malfunctions, misfires, or other issues do you think they might have run into? I just don't understand how something that MASSIVE with that much firepower would go unnoticed.